# Can I use Microsoft Sync Framework to synchronize two SQL 2008 databases?

Tags: .net, microsoft-sync-framework

I've seen examples about synchronizing SQL 2008 with SQL CE. But not two SQL 2008 databases.
If it can be done, have you seen example code about how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible with the new providers for the [Collaboration Scenario](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb902853(SQL.105).aspx) in Sync Framework 2.0.

The catch is that you will not be able to use SQL Server 2008's Change Tracking feature. The provider will add stored procedures and triggers etc to your database schema.

Answer (score 1):

I found good information about this here:

http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/synctechnicaldiscussion/thread/a3875382-a768-4125-ac59-b58a0a0e2c41