# Using Microsoft Sync Framework to synchronize two identical SQL Server 2012 databases using Change Tracking

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2012, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

I'm currently evaluating options for synchronizing two identical databases that will be deployed on two different SQL Server <sup>(1)</sup> instances. I've started with the Microsoft Sync Framework and if it does not fit my requirements I'll check SQL Replication.

Anyway, long story short, I'm trying to get a basic scenario to work using the Sync Framework but unfortunately all of the examples and tutorials I've seen online use the `SQL Provisioning Provider` which adds certain tables, stored procedures and triggers to the database - I want to avoid this, obviously.

I read somewhere that the Sync Framework can use SQL Server's built-in Change Tracking features, but this only works when the client is SQL CE ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820728/can-i-use-microsoft-sync-framework-to-synchronize-two-sql-2008-databases)). But all what I have read so far seems to be out-dated. I couldn't find anything that is relatively recent about the topic. So I was wondering whether the above is still valid or the Sync Framework added support for the built-in Change Tracking with SQL Server 2012 (or 2014).

In case this scenario is still not supported until this day, could someone refer me to an example (or at least some hints) of how I could develop a custom provider to use Change Tracking on both the client and the server?

(1) SQL Edition is not a constraint. Even SQL Server Enterprise Edition is an option.

Answer (score 0):

support for SQL Change Tracking only works for the older SqlCeClientSyncProvider/DBSyncProvider/SyncAgent, in short you can only use to sync SQL Ce with a SQL Server configured for SQL CT.

the newer sync providers do not support SQL CT.

there used to be a sample SQLExpressClientSyncProvider from MS that has been pulled out from the download site due as it has some issues.

Writing a custom sync provider is not easy, if you can go for SQL Replication, that will be an easier route.